# Ecto - select all fields from all tables in a 5 table join

Tags: ecto, elixir

I have a products table, a categories table, and a shops table, as well as joining tables product_shops, and product_categories.

I want to select all products that have a category which is in the conn.query_params, that are in shops that are within a certain distance which is specified in the conn.query_params. And I want to return pretty much every field of the product, category, and shop that was selected.

I have this:

```
  get "/products" do
    query = conn.query_params
    point = %Geo.Point{coordinates: {String.to_float(query["longitude"]), String.to_float(query["latitude"])}, srid: 4326}
    shops = within(Shop, point, String.to_float(query["distanceFromPlaceValue"]) * 1000) |> order_by_nearest(point) |> select_with_distance(point) |> Api.Repo.all
    categories = Enum.map(query["categories"], fn(x) -> String.to_integer(x) end)
    shop_ids = Enum.map(shops, fn(x) -> x.id end)

    query1 = from p in Product,
      join: ps in ProductShop, on: p.id == ps.p_id,
      join: s in Shop, on: s.id == ps.s_id,
      join: pc in ProductCategory, on: p.id == pc.p_id,
      join: c in Category, on: c.id == pc.c_id,
      where: Enum.member?(categories, c.id),
      where: Enum.member?(shop_ids, s.id),
      select: p, c, s,
      group_by s,
      order_by s.distance
```

In the code above, the `shops` variable holds all the shops that are within the specified distance.

this is inside shop.ex to get all shops within distance, ordered from the closest shop:

```
  def within(query, point, radius_in_m) do
    {lng, lat} = point.coordinates
    from(shop in query, where: fragment("ST_DWithin(?::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), ?), ?)", shop.point, ^lng, ^lat, ^point.srid, ^radius_in_m))
  end

  def order_by_nearest(query, point) do
    {lng, lat} = point.coordinates
    from(shop in query, order_by: fragment("? <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?,?), ?)", shop.point, ^lng, ^lat, ^point.srid))
  end

  def select_with_distance(query, point) do
    {lng, lat} = point.coordinates
    from(shop in query, select: %{shop | distance: fragment("ST_Distance_Sphere(?, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?,?), ?))", shop.point, ^lng, ^lat, ^point.srid)})
  end
```

This is the shop schema and the distance field gets populated when the `select_with_distance` variable is called.

```
  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:name, :place_id, :point]}
  schema "shops" do
    field :name, :string
    field :place_id, :string
    field :point, Geo.Point
    field :distance, :float, virtual: true

    timestamps()
  end
```

My current error is in the `select: p, c, s` line as I'm unsure how to select the whole lot:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/api/router.ex ==
** (SyntaxError) lib/api/router.ex:153: syntax error before: c
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

Also unsure if the group_by should be the shop. I just know I want to return all fields and only unique fields, ordered by proximity of the shop. I feel most of the way there but a bit stuck on the `select`, `group_by`, and `order_by`.

**EDIT:** Thanks Dogbert for fixing those two issues in the comments.

currently code is:

```
products_shops_categories = from p in Product,
  join: ps in ProductShop, on: p.id == ps.p_id,
  join: s in Shop, on: s.id == ps.s_id,
  join: pc in ProductCategory, on: p.id == pc.p_id,
  join: c in Category, on: c.id == pc.c_id,
  where: c.id in ^categories,
  where: s.id in ^shop_ids,
  select: {p, c, s}
  group_by s,
  order_by s.distance
```

I have this error now:

```
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) `order_by(s.distance())` is not a valid query expression.

* If you intended to call a database function, please check the documentation
  for Ecto.Query to see the supported database expressions

* If you intended to call an Elixir function or introduce a value,
  you need to explicitly interpolate it with ^

    expanding macro: Ecto.Query.group_by/2
    lib/api/router.ex:155: Api.Router.do_match/4
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

Comment: You can do `select: {p, c, s}` to get a 3-tuple back. Is that what you want?

Comment: Also, `Enum.member?(foo, bar)` inside queries should be `bar in foo`.

Comment: @Dogbert Thanks! I think a tuple will do the job although I am sending back to the frontend with Poison, I can convert to a list. I have just updated my question with the current error. Cheers!

Comment: Missing `:` from `group_by` and `order_by`

Comment: @MikeBuhot Thanks :)